# Tracking banner views

Tags: php, javascript

I would like some help with a way of tracking banner views with PHP and JS. I know how to track banner clicks but I fail to see a way of tracking views.

Answer (score 3):

If your banner is an image, you could replace it's URL with a PHP script that logs views and returns an image.

For example : `<img src="http://img.com/img.png">` --> Rewrite on a PHP script --> Log --> Return image

Comment: I'm not getting this. Can you provide more info please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently store how many times a banner/image has been viewed, modify the table in your database that contains id(s) for images.

table-banner

`id`|`path`|`clicks`|`views`

**www.example.org/products.php?products=type_a**

```
<?php
// other code
$type = $_GET["products"];
// sanitize $type
$views;
$products_selected = get_product_ids_from_type($type);
$query = "..."; // use $products_selected to create a query that will help to get image records from table
while($row = mysql_fetch_row(...)) { 
  echo "<img src='".$row[1]."' />";
  $views[$row[0]] = $row[3]; // get the old number of views
}
foreach($products_selected as $id) {
$query = "insert into `table-banner` (`views`) values ('".($views[$id] + 1)."') where id=`".$id."`;";
// perform the query
}
```

---

This means that when someone clicks on the link **www.example.org/products.php?products=type_a**, the request goes to the server and because `type_a` products are selected, your .php file will use that type to fetch id(s) and show the corresponding images, and while those images are fetched for display, at the same time you update the view column for each image record

In case you also want to use JavaScript (which is not necessary for this), you can

```
<script>
var selected_ids = [
<?php
  foreach($products_selected as $v) {
    echo $v.",";
  }
?>
];</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
   for(x in selected_ids) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: { id: selected_ids[x] }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( selected_ids[x] + " now has views : " + msg );
    });
   }
  });
</script>
```

**www.example.org/ajax.php**

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
// create connection
$view = 0;
$query = ...; // get old views from id and store in $view
// perform the query to insert new view
$query = "insert into `table-banner` (`views`) values ('".($view + 1)."') where id = `".$id."`;";
echo $view;
```

Comment: omg, it is closed now !! :D